Difference between and meaning of "rav" and "rabbi"
B"H
The terms Rav (רב) and Rabbi (רבי) appear in front of different people in the Gemara.
What is the difference between the two terms? I heard from a source I don't remember that Rabbi with the Yud represents bittul, implying they have smicha, while Rav itself just means "great".
But I thought people with Rav in their names also had smicha?
Is the modern usage of the terms Rav and Rabbi different than how they were used in the Gemara? Nowadays it seems like Rav is a more esteemed title than Rabbi
Is there a relation between Hashem being the Ribon רבון , Master of the universe, and Rabbis, who are also like "masters" of the world when they give a psak din?
Are there any similarities between the rabbinical title Raban רבן and Ribon רבון?
